# Rename folder in Pycharm without Pycharn no longer finding it

Tags: directory, pycharm, rename

There is a spelling mistake in the name of the folder where my whole project is. I would therefore like to rename the folder. Every time I try to rename the folder, Pycharm can't find the folder and I can't access the project. So I would like to know how to rename the folder.

I renamed the folder in explorer and then the connection to pycharm broke and I had to rename it back. I also gave the project a name because I thought I would rename the folder but that didn't work either. I tried to rename the path but I couldn't do it.

So my question is: How can I rename a folder without breaking the connection?